# HTML table using rowspan and colspan

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a HTML table like in this image;

[image: Achive the table attached in html]

I tried the following but it did not work.

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">1,1</th>
        <td>1,1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1,1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1,1</td>
        <td colspan="2">1,1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It **did** work. It's just the columns aren't equally sized. Add some CSS to set the widths.

Comment: If you want to use this for layout, you should really look into CSS, otherwise the page will not be responsive. If you want to use this for data tables, you are creating accessibility headaches for screen reader users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
<col width=100><col width=100><col width=100>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: none;">1,1</td>
      <td>1,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border-top: none;"></td>
      <td>2,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>3,1</td>
      <td colspan="2">3,2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is it possible to achieve above table using only html no css.

Comment: @BishalUdash Yes, you can remove all css styles from my answer and try again. My css styles is just used to make the table *looks like* your image.

Answer (score 2):

hi your code is good just add with to see the difference

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="width: 95px;">1,1</th>
        <td>1,1</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1,1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20px;">1,1</td>
        <td colspan="2">1,1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could build the table in your picture by using [`rowspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_rowspan.asp) and [`colspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_colspan.asp):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">1,1</td>
    <td>1,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2,3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3,1</td>
    <td colspan="2">3,2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```